# Can I create namespace without putting file inside folder structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `foo.rb` file inside a `lib` directory. Can I do something like this

```
module A
  module B
    class Foo
    end
  end
end
```

I don't want to create folder inside lib directory like this `lib/A/B/foo.rb`. I just want to place file inside lib directory like this `lib/foo.rb`. Is this possible in Rails? I am getting `uninitialized constant A (NameError)` when trying to create new object like this `A::B::Foo.new`

I am able to create object if i copy/paste above code directly into rails console. But if write that code inside `lib/foo.rb` file then I am not able to create new object.

**Upadate**

I already have `lib` directory in autoload path

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: IIRC, `lib` is not in Rails' autoload paths so you have to either add it or `require` the file manually.

Comment: @Stefan  I have already added lib directory to autoload path. Problem remains same even if i move `foo.rb` to `app/models`. Problem is with namespace not autoload.

Comment: @r3b00t Rails in general and its autoload machinery in particular are based on certain conventions. For it to be able to resolve `A` constant the file should be named `lib/a.rb` not `lib/foo.rb` (plus `lib` should be in autoload paths) - otherwise you would need to require it explicitly.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov didn't work after changing filename from `foo.rb` to `a.rb`. lib is already in autoload path.

Comment: Try `spring stop`

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov same error `uninitialized constant A (NameError)`

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I just want to be able to create `A::B::Foo.new` without adding files to folder.

Comment: Do you have `module A` or `module B` in any other file? (e.g. a `lib/bar.rb` that defines `A::B::Bar`) If so, Rails' autoloader might conclude that it has already read the file that defines `A` or `B`. In this case, removing `lib` from the autoload path and having a `require` for each file under `lib` might work.

Comment: @Stefan no i don't have `module A` and `module B` define is any other file. This is only one file where i am using namespace `A::B::Foo`

Comment: And does it work when you remove `lib` from the autoload path and have a `require` call for `lib/foo.rb`?

Comment: @Stefan it works when i require file manually `require lib/foo.rb`. I sill have autoload path for lib directory

Comment: @Stefan can we make it work without using `require lib/foo.rb`. any suggestions ?

Comment: I might be wrong on this but I _think_ you either have to follow Rails' naming conventions or `require` the files yourself. However, the latter can be automated quite easily, e.g. via `Dir.glob('lib/**/*.rb') { |f| require(f) }`

Comment: @r3b00t I cannot reproduce your error: putting your `A::B::Foo` definition in `lib/a.rb` and adding `lib` to autoload_paths in `config/application.rb` in a fresh Rails dummy project leads to `A`, `A::B` and `A::B::Foo` properly resolved. Which rails version are you using?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I am using rails 7. does it work if your filename is `foo.rb` rather than `a.rb`? For me neither filename worked.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov are you also able to do `A::B::Foo.new` ?

Comment: @r3b00t again, for the nested definition that you posted the file **must** be named `lib/a.rb` to be resolvable by the constant autoloading machinery. If you for some reason need it to be named `lib/foo.rb`, or you don't want to rely on autoloading, just require it explicitly. Answering the last question, yes, obviously `A::B::Foo.new` works for me too.

Comment: As an alternative you could try using https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-system/main/, it takes some time getting used to but works like a charm once up and running.

Comment: If you do not want to create the `a` and `b` subdirectories, also consider if you even need the nesting? Can you just create a class `Foo` and place it under `foo.rb`? Why do you need it to be `A::B::Foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Put code in `lib/a/b/foo.rb` which is how Rails conventions go. Rails autoloader will find the class there.
2. Put the code in `lib/a.rb` so when autoloader looks for the namespace `A` it will load it, find the class you're referencing.
3. Manually require `lib/foo.rb` in an initializer (credit to Stefan)
4. Manually require `lib/foo.rb` in every place you're referencing it.

I don't know why anyone would pick option 3 but you're free to ignore Rails conventions and do your own thing. Your life will be much easier however if you follow the convention.

Comment: _"require lib/foo.rb in every place you're referencing it"_ – or `require` it once globally, e.g. in an initializer.

Comment: Great point @Stefan, added to the answer. Feel free to edit so you get due credit :)